# Is there a word for the feeling like you have a spider on you?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, sometimes when you see a spider, or walk through a spider web, you have this terrible sensation of having a spider crawling on you, even though you know for a fact that it isn't happening. Is there a word for that feeling?

Comment: Also see *horripilation.*

Comment: I'd call it an "over-active imagination" and somebody's been reading or watching too many science-fiction stories. :)

Comment: Delusional parasitosis (Ekbom's syndrome), *...imaginary parasites are reported as being "bugs" or insects crawling on or under the skin; in these cases the experience of the sensation known as formication may provide the basis for this belief.* WP

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is *[formication](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/formication)*:-

> **noun** a tactile hallucination involving the belief that something is crawling on the body or under the skin.

The term originally referred to ants, but should serve quite well for spiders.

Comment: Also, Delusional parasitosis (Ekbom's syndrome), *...imaginary parasites are reported as being "bugs" or insects crawling on or under the skin; in these cases the experience of the sensation known as formication may provide the basis for this belief.* WP

Answer (score 5):

If you felt like you had a spider walking on you I would say you have the **[heebie jeebies](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=heebie%20jeebies)**.

> Urban Dictionary
>
> A feeling of minor fright, anxiety, nervousness, apprehension, "the
>   willies", phobic
>
> That spider crawling on my neck gave me the heebie jeebies

Comment: I understand "have the heebie jeebies" as "be nervous or depressed", and feel it is familiar but not really street-language. (British English - perhaps it is different in The States ?)

Comment: +1. Wisconsin weighing in here. I've heard the heebie jeebies used this way, see also the creepy-crawlies.

Answer (score 4):

It's called ***Ekbom's syndrome***, a condition of 'invisible bug infestation' - a delusional belief that insects are crawling under the skin (basically a tactile hallucination) - and hence known as ***delusional parasitosis.***

It was first described in 1938 by a Swedish neurologist after whom it is eponymously designated, and it is synonymous with *dermatophobia*, and *parasitophobic neurodermatitis*. One interesting feature of this condition is that it has been known to be psychologically contagious affecting another close associate (much like yawning) - a phenomenon known as *Folie a Deux* or madness between two.

Another pathologized name for this condition is [***Morgellons***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgellons).

Answer (score -1):

The real sensation would be a tickle (very general term) ; if it is only in the mind, and specific to spiders, it is called arachnophobia.